# SoapMessage.writeTo throws No Content exception for SOAPMessage with Attachments

Tags: java, soap, saaj

I am fetching the attachments from a SOAP message and using them in my application.
 I am not removing the attachments from the original message.
After that I am trying to convert the original **SOAPMessage containing attachments (SwA)** to a String using following code :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
soapMsg.writeTo(stream);
String message = new String(stream.toByteArray(), "utf-8");
```

It throws following exception :

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl writeTo
SEVERE: SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1233)
    at main.SOAPMTOMUtilityTest.main(SOAPMTOMUtilityTest.java:161)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.MessagingException: no content
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:905)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1224)
    ... 1 more

CAUSE:

com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.MessagingException: no content
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:905)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:266)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1224)
    at main.SOAPMTOMUtilityTest.main(SOAPMTOMUtilityTest.java:161)
```

Does anyone has idea about this ?

_Thanks,
Bhushan

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using a StringBuilder instead of a String?  Using `StringBuilder.append()` as seen below works for me, whereas I could not get a newly instantiated (as you were using) `String()` to work at all.

```
        // This stringbuilder will hold the initial message we sent to SOA
        StringBuilder soapMsg = new StringBuilder();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        SOAPMessage message = getSoapMessageFromString(foo);

        // Write the initial message to the byte array output string
        message.writeTo(baos);

        // append the baos data (initial message) to the stringbuilder for
        // processing
        soapMsg.append(baos.toString());

        // Reset the baos for use on the response message
        baos.reset();
```

Comment: 'message.writeTo(baos);' // this line fails internally

Comment: The second message says "no content."  Can you add a breakpoint somewhere before you attempt to write and check the object to make sure there is actually data in the message object?

Comment: Yes, data is present, however, this is something to do with the handlers !